# Data from PHP-include not shown in parent when using variable variable

Tags: php, jquery

I experience the following problem. By clicking the button in start.php the file fakten02.php is called with the parameter `DE2` . This parameter is used as a variable variable to convert the array `$DE2` into a string and display it in start.php. Unfortunately, this does not happen. If fakten02.php is directly called with the parameter, it works. If the parameter is hard-coded in fakten02.php the content of `$land` is shown in start.php. However, if `$land` is filled from `$text2`, `$land` is empty in start.php.

**start.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Start</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="spalten">
            <button type="submit" id="land1">Klicken</button>
        </div>
        <?php
            include("fakten02.php");
            print_r($land);
        ?>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#spalten > button").click(function() {
                $.get("fakten02.php", {sland:'DE2'});
                <?php echo $land; ?>;
            })
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

**fakten02.php**

```
<?php
    $parameter = $_GET['sland'];
    //$parameter=$_REQUEST['sland'];
    //print_r($_REQUEST);
    $DE2 = array("ich", "bin", "groß");
    //echo "Text $text";
    //$text2 = "$".$parameter;
    $param2 = $parameter;
    $text2 =$$param2;
    for ($i=0; $i < count($text2); $i++) {
        $land.="$text2[$i] "; //Does not work
        $land.= "daten[$i] = '$DE2[$i]';"; //Returns expected data
    }
    //print( "aus 2 $land, $param2");
?>
```

I don't understand this behaviour. I did a lot of searching here and on Google, but I could not find a similar problem. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, JS runs on the client. When your `<?php echo $land; ?>` is executed, it will be the value of $land at the time the script ran on the **SERVER**, not the value that came back from your client-side `$.get()` call. In other words, you have a fundamental misunderstanding on how PHP and JS interact, and WHERE and WHEN they get executed.

Comment: maybe he is using Titanium :P

Comment: Word of advice - if you find yourself needing to use variable variables, you're *probably* looking at the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: @Marc B Sorry for the late answer, got no notification. But you are right, I use $.getJSON() and it works. Thanks!